# Include Git commit hash and/or branch name in C/C++ source

Tags: c++, c, git, eclipse-cdt

I would like to know how you can get a Git commit hash and/or other information into the contents of a C++ variable in the compiled binary without having it be part of the source that's tracked by Git.

I need to keep track of firmware release information in a compiled executable running on an embedded processor. Means to identify the particular release of the firmware binary such as meaningful filenames, MD5 checksums or even date/time stamps are not available in this closed environment (i.e., there is no filesystem).

One approach is to have the device's console output produce identifying text, such as 'Release 1.2.3', 'commit hash 1bc123...', or similar. The firmware release information is only of interest to maintenance personnel, so a trained operator could examine the console output. To implement this it could potentially involve manual editing of a version string, which is then compiled into the code and output to the console at program startup.

This is acceptable for major releases where a signoff workflow is used to double-check that the version information is correct. However, this being a manual process it is inherently unreliable. For example, what if the developer forgets to update the version information? - There is now a disconnect between the compiled code and its reported version string.

A workflow where the code is freshly compiled and downloaded each time the user wants to test the hardware is not practical in the situation in question, ie., it is quite onerous to update the firmware.

An automatic way of identifying the version of the code is thus required. In the situation in question, Git is used, and the developers regularly commit their work to feature branches. Displaying the Git commit hash, and perhaps also whether or not there are unstaged changes, would be a way of identifying the status of the source code used to compile the firmware.

The requirement is that I would like my application to have information available to it so that it is able to display:
"Git commit:[01abcdef...etc], branch: experimentalStuffDoNotRelease"

Thus, I would like to automatically include Git information, such as commit hash and branch, in the compiled C and/or C++ code.

The development environment has developers using both Windows and Linux, and uses Eclipse CDT with a relatively unsophisticated workflow of: check out; compile; download to the hardware.

Comment: This would be a better question if you just boiled it down to the essentials: leave out all the workflow stuff, and just ask how you can get a git commit hash and/or other info into the contents of a C++ variable in the compiled binary without having it be part of the source that's tracked by git.  (knowing what the good answers look like should make this easier).  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351446/lifting-the-review-ban.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks - I actually added more information as I had a 'too broad' curse put upon it. Also, I specifically wanted to target eclipse because it wasn't using a standard 'make' workflow (AFAIK).

Comment: You should edit it so the real question is clear early on.  You can give details on why you want it later, after stating the specific question.  Asking how to do this for an Eclipse build seems pretty specific to me.  All the talk about workflow is a distraction, and opens things up to possible alternate solutions and is maybe what makes it too broad.  Your use-case is just one of many reasons that it's handy to have a program be able to print its version info including a commit id.

Comment: Oh, just looked at your first version.  Instead of asking how to get your app to display it, ask how to get the git version info into a variable at build time, without having the version string as part of the version-controlled source.  Asking how to display it is definitely too broad; we'll leave that part up to you after getting the version string into a CPP macro or global variable.

Answer (score 22):

I use a makefile, like so:

```
GIT_HASH=`git rev-parse HEAD`
COMPILE_TIME=`date -u +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC'`
GIT_BRANCH=`git branch | grep "^\*" | sed 's/^..//'`
export VERSION_FLAGS=-DGIT_HASH="\"$(GIT_HASH)\"" -DCOMPILE_TIME="\"$(COMPILE_TIME)\"" -DGIT_BRANCH="\"$(GIT_BRANCH)\""

all:
    g++ main.cpp $(VERSION_FLAGS)
```

When the makefile is run, the git hash and the time of compilation are both loaded into macros accessible within the source, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::cerr<<"hash="<<GIT_HASH<<", time="<<COMPILE_TIME<<", branch="<<GIT_BRANCH<<std::endl; 
}
```

Which gives output like:

```
hash=35f531bf1c959626e1b95f2d3e1a7d1e4c58e5ec, time=2017-05-18 04:17:25 UTC, branch=master
```

Comment: You can generally get the *branch* without calling both `grep` and `sed`, (e.g. `GIT_BRANCH=$(git branch | sed -n 's/^[*][ ]//p')`)

Comment: These macro's also work for Fortran with the fpp preprocessor (in ifort or gfortran).

Comment: also you can get branch name `GIT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`

Answer (score 8):

In Eclipse CDT, use a pre-build step to generate an include file containing the relevant information, and a conditional inclusion to check that the file was created:

1. Right-click the project
2. Select *Properties*
3. Expand the C/C++ Build
4. Select *Settings In the Build Steps* tab
5. Enter the following in the Command text box:

   ```
     git log --pretty=format:'#define GIT_INFO_PRESENT%n static const char* GIT_INFO = "Version Information=[%H,%d]\r\n";' -n 1 > ../src/gitcommit.h
   ```

   This will, upon build, create a file `gitcommit.h` that will be included in the source code. To customise it, adjust the string to your needs. (See https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)

As an example, I produce a debug output at the beginning of the main routine to inform the user of the commit and branch (not strictly needed knowing the commit, but certainly helpful):

1. Put this in the file, probably at the top

   ```
    #if __has_include("gitcommit.h")
    #include "gitcommit.h"
    #else
    static const char* GIT_INFO = "Git version information not present.\r\n";
    #endif
   ```
2. To display the information somewhere in your code, do similar to this:

   ```
    printf(GIT_INFO);
   ```

Note that I haven't, in this case, made the pre-build step a shell script or Windows/DOS `.bat` file, as I work often in Linux or Windows.

Note that this isn't tested in Windows.

In both cases, 'git' must be executable from the standard command line.

There is a dependency on provision of `__has_include`. This was intended to provide simplicity so that a default include file need not be provided.

Note that the `gitcommit.h` file's path should be discoverable by the compiler.

Comment: This is a great approach, however I'm using windows and eclipse keeps throwing the error that it cannot find git command. The PATH is updated and git works in any cmd. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Try something like `${ProjDirPath}/test.bat` and put something like "echo Hello" in there first. Sometimes you will see "System cannot find the path specified" for other reasons such as the script trying to access a file by a relative path meanwhile it is being called from a different working directory (see `%~dp0`)

Answer (score 3):

Usually as part of your build you run some command that generates something like that.
For example, `git describe` gives you something that you could use:

```
echo // auto generated version: > version.h
git describe > echo // auto generated version: > version.h
echo -e "#define VERSION " >> version.h
git describe >> version.h
```

For example x264 use [this simple script](https://github.com/mirror/x264/blob/master/version.sh) to generate it:

```
if [ -d .git ] && command -v git >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    localver="$(($(git rev-list HEAD | wc -l)))"
    if [ "$localver" -gt 1 ] ; then
        ver_diff="$(($(git rev-list origin/master..HEAD | wc -l)))"
        ver="$((localver-ver_diff))"
        echo "#define X264_REV $ver"
        echo "#define X264_REV_DIFF $ver_diff"
        if [ "$ver_diff" -ne 0 ] ; then
            ver="$ver+$ver_diff"
        fi
        if git status | grep -q "modified:" ; then
            ver="${ver}M"
        fi
        ver="$ver $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD | cut -c 1-7)"
        version=" r$ver"
    fi
fi

echo "#define X264_VERSION \"$version\""
echo "#define X264_POINTVER \"0.$ver\""
```

This will generate something like:

```
#define X264_VERSION  " r2708 86b7198"
#define X264_POINTVER "0.148.2708 86b7198"
```

Comment: Several commands in that script can be enormously simplified, e.g., `ver_diff=$(git rev-list --count origin/master..HEAD)` and `ver=$(git rev-parse --short=7 HEAD)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's simple solution if you need git hash and local modifications flag only:

```
$ cat update-version-info.sh

#!/bin/sh
version=$(git describe --always --dirty --tags)
echo "#define GIT_VERSION \"$version\"" > git-version.h

$ cat 1.c

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "git-version.h"

int main() {
#ifdef GIT_VERSION
    printf("%s\n", GIT_VERSION);
#endif
    return 0;
}

$ ./1

ee4f307-dirty
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Richard's answer and my fixes for qmake/Qt, here is the solution I use:
With Qt 5.14 the following lines in .pro file work for me:

```
GIT_HASH="\\\"$$system(git -C \""$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_"\" rev-parse --short HEAD)\\\""
GIT_BRANCH="\\\"$$system(git -C \""$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_"\" rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\\\""
BUILD_TIMESTAMP="\\\"$$system(date -u +\""%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SUTC\"")\\\""
DEFINES += GIT_HASH=$$GIT_HASH GIT_BRANCH=$$GIT_BRANCH BUILD_TIMESTAMP=$$BUILD_TIMESTAMP
```

In your code you can check the revision like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QStringList args;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        args << QString(argv[i]);

    if (args.contains("-v") || args.contains("--version")) {
        std::cout << QString("branch: %1, version: %2, built_at: %3").arg(GIT_BRANCH).arg(GIT_HASH).arg(BUILD_TIMESTAMP).toUtf8().constData() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A C file or a C++ file can be *generated* by some program (for example, some shell script on Linux, or some [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) script, or your C program running [system](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) or [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) running some `git` command).

You just configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. your `Makefile` if you use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), or your `build.ninja` file if you use [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)) appropriately.

Both [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) and [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) are doing so and keep their git id inside the obtained executable (displaying it when invoked with  `--version`). Note: both are projects I created.

PS a different question is how to configure your IDE to run a particular build automation tool. This is specific to your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). But [Eclipse CDT FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#When_do_I_use_the_managed_make_feature) offers an insight.