# Eclipse does not find git on windows installation

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm using eclipse in windows for embedding programming. Naturally git is a big part of my work and I want to keep track of hashes in my code. I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038428/include-git-commit-hash-and-or-branch-name-in-c-c-source) question, and many similar ones to have the git hash as a preprocessor micro. So added `git log -1 --pretty=format:'#define GIT_HASH %h' > ../Inc/gitinfo.h` to pre-build step.

The trouble is that eclipse does not find git even though it is in the path (git works in windows cmd), and egit is also installed on my eclipse (Neon 4.6.3).

Also tried to add the command in a batch file and run that file in the pre-build using `cmd /c "../../mybatchfile.bat"` which throws `'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`.

I would appreciate any guidance on that.

Comment: Is the Git integration installed? You can add that through the install new software option. Here's a my [git install info](http://imgbox.com/mMjzEMjf).

Comment: @PaulT. Yes, it is installed.

Comment: Try using backslash `\ ` instead of slash in path to batch file: `"..\..\mybatchfile.bat"`. Cmd complains about slash use.

Comment: The problem was that TM terminal was not installed in my eclipse! it's working now. Also thanks for the backslash input.